# HSSFSheet POI API Java doesn't fill all columns with color

Tags: java, excel, api, apache-poi

I am using POI to export some data to .xslx, but some columns are not filled with color, I use a loop, so it should work, it does for most of the columns. So what's wrong?

```
for (int i = 0; i < columnNamesFase1.length; i++) {
    HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short) i);
    cellA1.setCellValue(columnNamesFase1[columnCount]);
    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_ORANGE.index);
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    worksheet.autoSizeColumn(columnCount);
    columnCount++;
}
```

here is the .xslx file for example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41330678/new.xls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell Styles apply to the whole workbook, and so should never be created in a loop. They can (and should) be re-used, and there's a fairly low limit on the number that a given Workbook can contain (imposed by the Excel file format)

You should therefore change your code to be more like:

```
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_ORANGE.index);
cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

for (int i = 0; i < columnNamesFase1.length; i++) {
   HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short) i);
   cellA1.setCellValue(columnNamesFase1[columnCount]);
   cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
   worksheet.autoSizeColumn(columnCount);
   columnCount++;
}
```

Additionally, auto-sizing a column is a very slow step, so should only be done once you have written all rows